# makeselfinst: Cannot install to /opt/chef

Tags: macos, chef-infra

Trying to run:

```
sudo curl -L https://www.opscode.com/chef/install.sh | bash
```

I'm getting error message:

```
makeselfinst: Cannot install to /opt/chef
```

How do I get Chef to fully install on OSX?

Comment: `curl -L https://www.opscode.com/chef/install.sh | sudo bash` ?!

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? It's okay to answer your own question. Please don't forget to mark an answer as correct! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Omnibus installer for a simple, one line install command:

```
curl -L https://www.opscode.com/chef/install.sh | sudo bash
```

The `sudo` comes before the bash, not the `curl`.

In your example, you are running the "download" command as root, but the install command as a general user. They should be flipped - all users can download things, but only privileged users can install them.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up temporarily `chmod 777` on `/opt/chef` and `/usr/bin` as well as `chown -R myuser /opt/chef`

That seemed to clear up the issues with running the curl command.